# Problem getting rid of theme error

Tags: 7, upgrading

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in `includes/theme.inc on line 980`
```

In my homepage im getting that error. I have no idea why I keep getting that error.

I'm on the process of upgrading my Drupal 6 to Drupal 7.

Thanks

Comment: Do you still have the old theme in your new installation? If so try deleting the old theme folder and the error *should* go away.

Comment: @stefgosselin no I don't have I already deleted them all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to impossible to know where this error come from without adding some debug statements before the line 980.

Try enabling devel.module and adding following code on line 977:

```
dpm(func_get_args());
dpm($info);
```

This will reveal which theme hook is being called and its parameters (variables). It should give enough clues to help you find where the error comes from.